# Windows 10: Libraries folder pin bug

Tags: windows-10, windows-explorer

I'm using Windows 10 b1703 (Portuguese-BR language) and i'm trying to pin the Libraries folder in Quick Access.

But instead of showing the fancy icon and the translated text i'm get a unstranslated default folder icon:

[image: image describing the problem]

Does anyone know why this happens? In earlier versions when i pin Libraries folder i always got the translated text and the icon. But in later updates i always got this.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you have any other language packs installed other than Portuguese?

Comment: @Ramhound nope, just Portuguese.